# Why does CodeIgniter store output in a variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

i recently looked through CodeIgniter's code just to see how it works.

One thing that i don't understand is why CodeIgniter is storing all the output generated by the views in a single variable and outputting it at the end of the script?

Here's a piece of code from ./system/core/Loader.php at line 870
[CI Source code @ GitHub](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/1d79efea47d26e0e567f919c648adf5b554f3ff0/system/core/Loader.php#L870)

```
/*
* Flush the buffer... or buff the flusher?
*
* In order to permit views to be nested within
* other views, we need to flush the content back out whenever
* we are beyond the first level of output buffering so that
* it can be seen and included properly by the first included
* template and any subsequent ones. Oy!
*/
if (ob_get_level() > $this->_ci_ob_level + 1)
{
    ob_end_flush();
}
else
{
    $_ci_CI->output->append_output(ob_get_contents());
    @ob_end_clean();
}
```

The function append_output appends the given string to a variable in the CI_Output class.
Is there a particular reason for doing this and not using echo statements or is it just a personal preference ?

Comment: Wouldn't a question like this be better suited for [CodeIgniter's forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/)?

Answer (score 6):

There are several reason. On reason is that you can load a view and have it returned rather than output directly:

```
// Don't print the output, store it in $content
$content = $this->load->view('email-message', array('name' => 'Pockata'), TRUE);
// Email the $content, parse it again, whatever
```

The third parameter `TRUE` buffers the output so the result is not printed to screen. WIthout that you'd have to buffer it yourself:

```
ob_start();
$this->load->view('email-message', array('name' => 'Pockata'));
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Another reason is that you cannot set headers after you have sent output, so for instance you can user `$this->output->set_content($content)`, then afterwards at some point set the headers (set content type headers, start a session, redirect the page, whatever) then actually display (or don't display) the content.

In general, I find it very bad form to have any class or function use `echo` or `print` (common in Wordpress for one example). I'd almost always rather use `echo $class->method();` than have it echo for me, for the same reasons outlined above - like being able to assign the content to a variable without it spilling into the output directly or creating my own output buffer.

Comment: Generally it's good practice to have control over your data (expanding on your last paragraph!) oh and I forgot about the email view part, which is the most common example!

Comment: For a general example `function greet($str){echo "Hello $str!";}`... `echo strtolower(greet('Andrew'));` <-- Does not work, would work if the function `return`ed instead. For `$this->load->view()` it makes sense to `echo`, but not every time a bit of output is set with the Output class.

Comment: That was my point haha! It gives more control over how to handle the data

Answer (score 4):

the answer is in the commenting in your post.

```
/**
* In order to permit views to be nested within
* other views, we need to flush the content back out whenever
* we are beyond the first level of output buffering so that
* it can be seen and included properly by the first included
* template and any subsequent ones. Oy!
*/
```

it's so you can go:

```
$view = $this->load->view('myview', array('keys' => 'value'), true);
$this->load->view('myotherview', array('data' => $view));
```